# Capital goods prices: data for Euro-area countries

Tags: monetary-policy

For my bachelor's degree work I'm trying to estimate the natural rate of interest for euro area and I'm doing this following three main approaches: the first one is the one that defines the natural rate as the rate of time preference (that I'm trying to estimate as the ratio between consumption and savings); the second one is the one that considers the natural rate as the marginal productivity of capital and the third one is the one that defines the natural rate as the rental cost of capital, estimated by the equation proposed in the Hall-Jorgenson model of investment:

*[(P(k)/P)(i-inf-d)]*

, where P(k) is the price of capital goods and P is a price deflator. My question is: where do I find the data for those two indicators for all the nineteen Euro-area countries? Thank in advance for your support!

Comment: Have you tried Eurostat?

Comment: To be honest, yes. But they have a small dataset that doesn't go back enough. I need datas from 1995 to 2021, and they have data only for 2021. If, within the Eurostat database, you can find older datasets it will be very appreciated!

Comment: In short, what I'm looking for is the time series for the Capital Goods Price index (or the Producer price index) and for the price deflator for Euro-area countries from 1994 (to calculate de % variation) to 2019

Comment: Don't give up on Eurostat just yet, as they do probably have an archive of past tables. Calling them or emailing would be the best thing to do, if you can find the representative of the particular department you are interested in.

Comment: Thank you! I'll do it as soon as possible (probably monday, since where I live is sunday today).